# ubuntu 18.03 says no wifi adapter found on dell inspiron 3543

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, dell

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop alongside window 8.1. Everything seems fine but it doesn't show wifi. It says `wifi adapter not found`. I have tried almost all the tricks and solution available till but it didn't help. My laptop have broadcom adapter and laptop is of dell inspiron 3543.
Please some one guide me.

Comment: You didn't specify which Ubuntu media you used (18.04, 18.04.1, 18.04.2, 18.04.3, 18.04.4, which shows age of stack, nor if using desktop, server etc), however your best starting point is the doco - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  (you'll find the Device Recognition & Operating in step 3 most hepful, it tells you the chipset used by your box allowing you to search online, or us to know what is on your motherboard, as brands regularly change components in models unless a short-term failed model that didn't see & was dropped quickly).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using other operating system on a "Live CD" to check if exists a damage on your WiFi physically, if your WiFi works correctly on the "Live CD", try verify if exists an official driver for your operative system. Regards.